# Error: Authentication failed in mongodb 4.4.4 running in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I used to run mongodb in docker with this config

**~/project/.env** file is

```
# Mongodb common config
CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27020
CONFIG_MONGODB_PREFIX=mongodb://
CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_ENABLED=true
CONFIG_MONGODB_USERNAME=alok
CONFIG_MONGODB_PASSWORD=alokm
CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_SOURCE=admin
```

**~/project/docker-compose.yml** file is

```
version: '3.4'

mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: mongod --port ${CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_MONGODB_DATA}:/data/db
    ports:
      - 5010:${CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT}
    expose:
      - ${CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT}
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${CONFIG_MONGODB_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${CONFIG_MONGODB_PASSWORD}
```

To run mongodb

```
sudo docker-compose up --build
```

To access mongodb from my laptop

```
mongo localhost:5010 --password alokm --username alok --authenticationDatabase admin
```

This all setup used to work fine without any extra setup.

But when I changed mongodb image from `mongo:4.0.3` to `mongo:4.4.4` and run freshly on another laptop I see

```
ubuntu@myhost:~/project$ mongo localhost:5010 --password alokm --username alok --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:5010/test
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("4282986e-eb0b-4a88-8d39-1295192a66e7") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.4
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
2021-04-16T01:41:18.225+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

Why my this setup is not working in case of `image: mongo:4.4.4` like it was working in case of `image: mongo:4.0.3`?

Comment: Have you tried using a modern client version?

Comment: @GertvandenBerg: what is modern client? Do you mean latest version?

Comment: A version within on version of the server that you are trying to connect to. (e.g. 4.2 or newer for connecting to 4.4) (The supported and default password hashes changed over time)